# I want to add Image in kibana dashboard

Tags: kibana

I want add image in kibana dasgboard but it gives me error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsSCY.png)

I was used Markdown to add image but giving me error which is shown in attached picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was successfully able to add the image to Kiban dashboard in the markdown widget as follows:

```
![Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsSCY.png)
```

Make sure you can acess the image from the web browser before trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload the image without reference to a URL or local folder you can use base64 image. You have to add a TSVB object on your dashboard. From there you can select markdown and and choose panel options to select "Custom CSS (supports Less)".

I would then do the following:

Example

```
p {
    height: 80px;
    width: 45px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,"yourbase64") !important;
}
```

This is a bit of a hacky way and large images can not be used but if you do not have access to a folder or web then this will work for you.